# math exchange switches me to wrong link

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

When I click on "complete list of questions" I am sent to "unanswered questions".  I did once click on "unanswered questions", and it seems to have upset something in the links

Comment: Below the main tab (with questions, users, badges, etc.), are you by any chance in the "unanswered" subtab? If so, please go to "newest" or "active" to solve this "bug".

Comment: The choice of "tabs", as described by Lord_Farin, is remembered by you computer (okay, a cookie). So once you choose a tab, the next time you use the site it will go to the same tab.

Comment: I did once go to the "unanswered" tab.  However, thereafter I clicked on the "complete list of questions" tab. That simply should not take me to unanswered questions -- if there is a cookie, it should be replaced at that point.  So what do I do to get rid of this?  And how do I dare look again at unanswered questions if I am going to get stuck there.